# get values from txt file perl

Tags: perl, command-line

i am trying to get two value from text file

my perl code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Fcntl qw( :flock :DEFAULT );

exit unless sysopen( PID, '1.pid', O_RDWR | O_CREAT ) && flock( PID, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB );
print PID "$$\n";

while(-s "1.txt")
{
 sleep 1;
 open(F,"1.txt")||die"12";
 my @arr=<F>;
 close F;
 exit if $#arr==-1;

 my $str=shift(@arr);

 open(F,">1.txt")||die"13";
 print F @arr;
 close F;

 $str=~s/[\n\r]+//g;
 my ($dx,$code)=$str=~/^(\d+):(\w+)$/;
 print"($dx)($code)\n";

}
```

my text file

```
00001:3wzhs7t2w5t2
00001:3wzhs7t2w5t3
00001:3wzhs7t2w5t4
```

my code output

```
()()
```

i need

```
$dx = 00001
$code = 3wzhs7t2w5t2
```

Comment: So you basically want to remove the first line of the file and write back the rest, then output the first line's contents parenthesized?  If that's accurate, I would suggest something shorter like `perl -i -ne 'if ($. == 1) { s/:/)(/; s/^/(/; s/$/)/; print STDERR } else { print }' 2>&1` instead.

Comment: remove line one by one and extract $dx = 00001 $code = 3wzhs7t2w5t2

after loop finish file will empty

Comment: Why do you think you have to re-write the file after each time you read a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little snippet that reads a file line by line and for each line outputs the constituents in two variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

open my $fh, '<', 'example.txt';

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ m/([^:]*):([^:]*)/) {
        my $dx = $1;
        my $code = $2;
    }

}
```

I hope I didn't do anybody's homework ;)